# Django template include/extend with subdirectories

Tags: django, django-templates

Considering the following directory:

```
|- basic.html
|- nav.html
|- folder1/
|- |- page.html
\- \- nav.html
```

`page.html` extends `../basic.html` which includes `nav.html`

In that case, its the `folder1/nav.html` that gets included. If I remove `folder1/nav.html`, *nothing* gets included. How do I fix this? I could inline `nav.html` into `basic.html`, but there might be situations down the road where I want to have `basic.html` do some includes.

edit: The idea is that anything that inherited basic.html would get the toplevel nav.html template, but that doesn't seem to be the case, because the `include nav.html` directive is evaluated in the current directory of whatever template.

Comment: can you comment on why you want to remove folder1/nav.html? it seems like you would just fix basic.html if you were to delete a file that it includes. of course, I understand you have your own circumstances, but I'm going to be that guy who says that there might be a different way to approach it.

Comment: It looks like the only way is to directly include the contents of nav.html in basic.html, which works, but I'd rather keep it separate - purely aesthetic reasons, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I get everything correctly, but i think you have to enclose the `include` with a `block`?

basic.html:

```
...
{% block navigation %}
{% include "nav.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

page.html:

```
{% extends "../basic.html" %}
{% block navigation %}
{% include "folder1/nav.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

If you do not overwrite the navigation block  in `page.html` the original include should be used...

Comment: That seems like it would work, but the point is that I don't want page.html to have to override `block navigation` unless it needs to display different data there.

Comment: What's the bad thing about overriding the block?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - the problem is that the `include` directive is evaluated within the current directory of page.html, rather than where the block was defined.